# Printing a string containing variable's actual value

Tags: java

I need to print a string in my console as below:

```
('23', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12 14)',2263));
```

Here a code in java to print the string(But gives error) :

```
// begin
    int var1=12;
    int var2=14;
    int light =23;

    String str=" ('"+ light+"','"+ ST_GeomFromText(POINT(var1 + " " + var2),2263)+"'); ";
    System.out.println(str);
//end
```

How can I print the required format

Thanks

Comment: When you claim an error, but don't bother to tell us *where* or *what* it is, it leaves a lot to guess work. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Either use:

```
String str =
   " ('" + light + "','ST_GeomFromText(POINT(" + var1 + " " + var2 + "),2263)')";
```

or:

```
String str =
   String.format(" ('%d','ST_GeomFromText(POINT(%d %d),2263)')", light, var1, var2);
```

`String.format` makes it easier to create text messages, because you don't have to clutter up the line with String concatenations.

Comment: Please see the edit, sorry I forgot to include that light is also a variable.